# Is Sitecore 9.1 admin password no longer 'b'?

Tags: sitecore-client

I read that in Sitecore 9.1 the admin user is no longer 'b'. Is that accurate?

Comment: I'm also facing the issue but I couldn't able to find it in XP0-SingleDeveloper.log. Could you please guide me in which place the password has been generated

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As per installation guide, in version 9.1 the Sitecore admin password needs now to be set when installing it.

"One of the settings that you must edit is SitecoreAdminPassword.
If you do not specify the Sitecore administrator password in the script and leave the example value
"SIF-Default" unchanged, a random password is generated for you. This password is written to the
XP0-SingleDeveloper.log file"

you can find in the installation guide [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/91/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_91_Initial_Release.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it helps

Answer (score 4):

That is true. Default password is set to "SIF-Default" which during installation is detected by SIF and SIF generates new / random password for you.

However, you can easily change that password back to "b" through **User Manager** if you are feeling nostalgic.

Mind that this could be a security risk! If you are planning to use this old password on dev machine, you are probably safe to change it to "b".